# Saving image for Looping

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying for use looping to get the figures of each my data. For example:

```
In [1]: data.shape
Out[1]: (5, 784)
```

Then i'm using this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(len(data)):
    x=plt.imshow(data[i].reshape(28,28), cmap="gray_r")
    plt.show()
    name='%s%s.png' % str(x[i])
    plt.imsave(name, x)
```

and i got error here:

```
TypeError: 'AxesImage' object does not support indexing
```

My goal is to get the save image for each loop without overwritten. But, i don't understand what should i do when i got this error. Because i'm new in python.

Comment: You're trying to use the `AxesImage` object `x` returned by `imshow` to make the filename from it. That doesn't make much sense. Replace `x[i]` with `i` in that line and remove the 2nd `%s` from the format string and you should get somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but i got error like this: `TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float`

Comment: In which line that is?

Comment: In line 618 raise TypeError. I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's some confusion here between

- plotting an image and saving the plot and
- just saving an image given as a numpy array

If the latter is what you want, which I guess, try this:

```
data = arange(5*784).reshape((5,784))  # test data

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    # for every row in date, reshape to 28x28 and save as image
    img = data[i].reshape(28,28)
    plt.imsave("{}.png".format(i), img, cmap="gray_r")
```

And if it's the former, try this. Note the axes and coordinate labels in the resulting images.

```
data = arange(5*784).reshape((5,784))   # test data

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    # for every row in date, reshape to 28x28, plot and save as image
    img = data[i].reshape(28,28)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray_r")
    plt.savefig("{}.png".format(i))
```

`plt.savefig` will contextually know that it's supposed to save the image that you plotted with `imshow` beforehand, so there's no need to pass any arguments other than the filename.

It might become necessary to clear the figure with `plt.clf()` in between, since `imshow` just "paints over" the current figure with the previous images from the loop on it. It worked without for this example when I tested it, though.

Comment: Hey, it works! Thanks for your help @Jeronimo. It helps me a lot because i'm still new in python and i still don't get it with python language program.